# My website does not connect properly with my domain?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, redirects, html5, multi-subdomains

I made a website in wix for free. I registered a free .tk domain and hosted the domain in 1freehosting.com. I used file2hd.com to save my wix website. After that i uploaded that file to the ftp so that people can view my website in a custom domain instead of wix subdomain. Right now my site is incomplete and i have only 2 pages.

Now the main problem:-
When i open my custom domain site and go to contact page and then again go to the home page it redirects to the wix subdomain site and i even deleted my wix site in wix editor so that it cannot redirect but then also it redirects to wix. What can i do to solve this problem? Is there a problem with the code? If yes what code should i change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hate to tell you this, but your webpage doesn't load in Opera 11, and based on the source code, it looks as if it requires a bunch of files and javascript just for something to possibly be displayed on the screen.

Comment: @Mike I used httrack also but it worked fine for my another website but now it doesn't work for this website it just opens a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. I just changed

```
"externalBaseUrl":"http:\/\/myaccount.wix.com/mysite"
```

to

```
"externalBaseUrl":"http:\/\/mydomain.tk"
```

in the HTML code. Thanks to the Darcy website ripper support for this solution.